# Darboux variables for $SU(3)$

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, yang-mills

In principle, for any $SU(N)$ group it is possible to construct Darboux variables (which are desired since they obey canonical commutation relations) corresponding to the color charges $Q_a$ (which satisfy Poisson brackets of the type $\{Q_a,Q_b\}_\mathrm{PB}=f_{abc}Q_c$). For example, according to $\eqref{2.17}$ from [P.F. Kelly, Q. Liu, C. Lucchesi, C. Manuel - Classical Transport Theory and Hard Thermal Loops in the Quark-Gluon Plasma](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9406285)
, for $SU(3)$ such variables may be introduced as

$$\begin{aligned}
&Q_{1}=\cos \phi_{1} \pi_{+} \pi_{-} && Q_{5}=S_{++} \pi_{+} A+S_{+-} \pi_{-} B\\
&Q_{2}=\sin \phi_{1} \pi_{+} \pi_{-} && Q_{6}=C_{-+} \pi_{-} A-C_{--} \pi_{+} B \\
&Q_{3}=\pi_{1} && Q_{7}=S_{-+} \pi_{-} A-S_{--} \pi_{+} B \\
&Q_{4}=C_{++} \pi_{+} A+C_{+-} \pi_{-} B && Q_{8}=\pi_{2} 
\end{aligned}\label{2.17}\tag{2.17}$$

where the additional $\pi_\pm$, $C_{\pm\pm}$, $S_{\pm\pm}$, $A$ and $B$ are defined shortly after, in the aforementioned article. The color charges $\{Q_a\}_{a=\overline{1,8}}$ are replaced by $\{\phi_1, \phi_2,\phi_3, \pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3, J_1, J_2\}$ with $\{\phi_i,\pi_j\}_\mathrm{PB}=\delta_{ij}$. On the other hand, $J_1$ and $J_2$ are fixed by the quadratic and cubic Casimir operators

$$\begin{aligned}
C^1_\mathrm{SU(3)}&=Q^{a} Q^{a}=\frac{1}{3}\left(J_{1}^{2}+J_{1} J_{2}+J_{2}^{2}\right) \\
C^2_\mathrm{SU(3)}&=d_{a b c} Q^{a} Q^{b} Q^{c}=\frac{1}{18}\left(J_{1}-J_{2}\right)\left(J_{1}+2 J_{2}\right)\left(2 J_{1}+J_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}\tag{2.21}\label{2.21}$$

In the fundamental representation, it is known that $C^1_F=4/3$ and $C^2_F=10/9$. Nevertheless, with these values, $\eqref{2.21}$ has as solutions only imaginary $J_1$ and $J_2$, as brutally checked [via Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems%20of%20equations%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%3D4%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28x-y%29%28x%2B2y%29%282x%2By%29%3D20%22). I am wondering if there is something dubious about these formulas since for some generic irreducible representation $D(m, n)$ of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ these Casimirs are (as proven using Freudenthal’s formula)

$$\begin{aligned}C^1_\mathrm{SU(3)}&=\frac{1}{3}(m^2+n^2+3m+3n+mn)\\
C^2_\mathrm{SU(3)}&=\frac{1}{18}(m-n)(m+2n+3)(2m+n+3)\end{aligned}$$

which for the fundamental representation $D(1,0)$ obviously give $C^1_F=4/3$ and $C^2_F=10/9$ but may not be equivalently reduced to something which looks like $\eqref{2.21}$.

Another question is related to the values which these canonical variables are allowed to take. For example, since $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ form an $SU(2)$ subgroup of $SU(3)$, it follows that $Q_1^2+Q_2^2+Q_3^2=\pi_3^2$ but since this is $C_\mathrm{SU(2)}=3/4$, $\pi_3$ is fixed. On the other hand, $Q_1=\cos \phi_{1} \sqrt{\pi_3^2-\pi_1^2}$ which constraints $-\pi_3\leq\pi_1\leq\pi_3$. But what about the others? This parametrization was first proposed in [K. Johnson - Functional integrals for spin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491689901206) (as far as I was able to find) where it is stated, for $SU(2)$, that the "angle" $\phi$ variables may take any value (not only bounded within $[-\pi, \pi])$.

Any suggestion or comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is evident that $J_1=m+1$ and $J_2=n+1$, and you have shifted your quadratic Casimir by 1. Casimirs are often defined by varying conventions.

Comment: How do you enforce unitarity in this construction, to quantize the Casimirs conventionally, as you do? Haven't seen your expected $S^3$ bundle over $S^5$ yet.

Comment: I also thought about this but was unsure about that shift in $C_1$. So it was somehow wrong for me to try to obtain $J_1$ and $J_2$ for $C_1=4/3$ without knowing what conventions they used in defining that Casimir.

Comment: As for the second comment, I don't know. I am still trying to comprehend this whole construction.

Comment: Ken Johnson appears to be considering more general Casimirs for SU(2)'s other families of reps beyond unitary ones. By contrast, your primary reference makes a nasty hash out of SU(2), and misunderstands the operator realization of the PB structure. Their "Casimir" is just a bland integration constant, not a gradient operator commuting with charge-driven generators.... Caveat lector!

Comment: Thank you, your remark is clarifying. Indeed, the Casimirs from the main reference enter merely as constants of integration. Nevertheless, they seem to be interested in just constructing a phase-space (for some transport theory) in which color charges are "more correctly" taken into consideration. This is all done in a classical context, with no aim to further quantize these Casimirs.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but in classical flows I see *no* restriction to the values of *J*, etc... so your comparing with unitary representation Casimir values appears optional.